# Native Android - Can't locate undefined method when loading a shared lib even though previously loaded shared lib contains the definition

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native

I am building an Android app that loads in 2 native shared libraries at runtime: 1 that was built with an unresolved symbol in it and the other which resolves and defines that symbol.  In Java, I load the shared library that defines the symbol first, then load the library that has the symbol declared as unresolved, and at this point, the runtime fails with:
"Cannot load library: reloc_library[]: 33 cannot locate 'someMethod'

So here's the one unique difference.  The shared library with the undefined symbol obviously doesn't know about the shared library with the definition for the symbol in it.

I just assumed that if I loaded the library with the definition of the method first that when I loaded the 2nd library that called the method, it would be able to find it.  Am I wrong on that?  It seems in my case, an explicit dependency HAS to be compiled in between the two native libs, which means (I think) making .so's with unresolved symbols is useless.

I have searched vigorously for a similar issue with no luck.  I think my problem is due to an architectural limitation, and I am considering approaching it a couple of other ways, but I would like to know if it can be fixed simply.

To be sure it wasn't some complexity of the library itself, I created two very simple C files:

```
fcn_defined.c:
int someMethod()
{
  return 1;
}

fcn_undefined.c:
extern int someMethod();
int someOtherMethod()
{
  someMethod();
}
```

Then build two shared objects where the fcn_undefined.c code creates a .so with someMethod still undefined and fcn_defined.c builds a .so with someMethod defined:

```
gcc -o libfcn_undefined.so fcn_undefined.c -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic
gcc -o libfcn_defined.so fcn_defined.c -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic
```

Doing a nm on these produces:

libfcn_undefined.so:

```
0001f08 d _DYNAMIC
00001fe8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00002004 A __bss_start
         U __cxa_atexit
         U __cxa_finalize
00002000 d __dso_handle
00000290 t __on_dlclose
00002004 A _edata
00002004 A _end
000002a0 t atexit
000002b4 T someOtherMethod
         U someMethod
```

and libfcn_defined.so:

```
00001f0c d _DYNAMIC
00001fec d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00002004 A __bss_start
         U __cxa_atexit
         U __cxa_finalize
00002000 d __dso_handle
0000025c t __on_dlclose
00002004 A _edata
00002004 A _end
0000026c t atexit
00000280 T someMethod
```

So you can see someMethod() is defined in libfcn_defined.so (and it appears in the read elf dynsym section) and is undefined in the other lib.

If anyone is interested in the readelf output, I can add that as well.

In the Java side, I have a simple button in the emulator that I click, and it creates a class with the following in it:

```
static
{
        System.loadLibrary("fcn_defined");
        System.loadLibrary("fcn_undefined");
}
```

Just out of curiosity, I added a "-lfcn_defined" to the fcn_undefined compile line, and compared the nm and readelf outputs.  the only difference in nm was that the "T someOtherMethod" started a few bytes further out and the readelf difference was the "NEEDED" line for fcn_defined.  That's pretty much about what I expected.  **And it doesn't crash like this.**

That's pretty much the full explanation.  I did find some details about how Android forces you to load your libraries in reverse dependency order in Java, because it has (rather it had, has been fixed in API 18) no reference to your app's lib path in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar.  Unfortunately, I am requiring a minimum API lvl 10 to be able to use my app because of the market penetration, and secondly I tried API 19 anyway, and it still fails.

If I had to guess, I believe Android just doesn't support finding a symbol if you haven't explicitly told it to look at library X for the symbol.  In other words, because I didn't build the library fcn_undefined with an explicit dependency on libfcn_defined.so, Android can't resolve it.  Does anyone know if this is a bug or by design?  Is this normal?  It seems like you wouldn't have the option to create a .so with unresolved symbols if this was the case, and even funnier is that the Android NDK toolchain I'm using to build this has this feature on by default when you use ld (it doesn't complain about unresolved), and I tried turning the feature off but didn't seem to do anything, no warnings or errors generating the library.

So you may ask why I don't just compile the fcn_undefined library with a dependency on the fcn_defined library.  Well that gets into a much bigger architectural discussion.  The code I'm working with (fcn_undefined.c in this example) is a python extension built with a cross compiled python toolchain for ARM, and I'm calling this library from an NDK library, so now the NDK library depends on the python module which has an unresolved method in Python, which is defined in a static lib.  Linking the static lib into the NDK shared lib means that I can't load the native shared libs in the correct order in Java (due to the issue mentioned previously that they fixed in API 18).  I'm trying to work with the existing system since a team of others use it, and it is used to build for many platforms.  *sigh*  I clearly have other things to figure out, but I was hoping to nail the one above down at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you so beautifully demonstrated is by design (or lack of, if you will). You are right in part, the crazy_linker does resolve some of such issues (but not all of them). There is an easy but ugly workaround. Build a dummy `libfcn_defined.so` which only has `T someMethod` in its **nm**. Use it to link `libfnc_undefined.so`, using `LD_LIBS`. NDK will show a warning, but that's OK. LAoad the real `libfcn_defined.so` in your Java.

Comment: Hmmm...That's an interesting approach I hadn't thought of.  In fact, all I needed to do was create an empty c file, make it "libfcn_defined.so", and link against that.Now, unfortunately I simplified my problem here too much, because I'm actually building an NDK library that statically linked the "defined" symbols that another .so requires, so I have a circular dependency, because the NDK library requires loading the secondary library which requires code that was statically linked into the NDK library.  This will definitely get me on my way though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By Unix/ELF design, you need a NEEDED entry in libfnc_undefined.so that lists libfnc_defines.so as a dependency for the dynamic linker to look into it for missing symbols.

I.e. you should ensure that -lfcn_defined (or /path/to/libfcn_defined.so) appears in the link command that generated libfcn_undefined.so.

If you use ndk-build to generate both libraries, just list libfcn_defined.so as a LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES entry for libfcn_undefined.so.

If you use another build system, adapt accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the technical answer.  I was torn between your answer and Alex's answer, but his was the best work around for my situation.  I do understand the problem better thanks to your answer.  As I somewhat suspected, it is an architectural limitation, not of Android like I thought, but of ELF.  In my build system, I can't link the full .so in at build-time due to several other constraints, 1) it doesn't exist.  Why allow an unresolved symbol if you require that the library that defines it be linked in?  To support the work around Alex mentioned maybe?  Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: I think you can actually solve this by creating an mock version of libfcn_defines.so that only defines the symbols you need (either as dummy variables or functions), then link libfnc_undefined.so against it.